# Why is date() returning the wrong month?

Tags: php

`date('F Y', strtotime('2013-05-00T00:00:00'));` returns the value `'April 2013'`, but I would expect it to return `'May 2013'`.

Is this an issue with `date()` interpreting the date string as still in April, or perhaps the format string? I tried `'M Y'`, which still gave me `'Apr 2013'`. Is there an alternative?

Comment: since when was '00' a day of the month?

Comment: Did you intentionally supplied 2013-05-**00** not 01 ?

Comment: I am surprised you got the right year, as the second argument of date is supposed to be an integer ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)). Besides that, '2013-05-00' is not a valid date either. Set it to '2013-05-01' and see if you still get the problem.

Comment: the `00`th day is allways the last day of the previous month, this can be observed if you add `d` to the format string. Which is actually a nice feature if you're explicitly looking for that day, which otherwise can be quite annoying to get a hold of.

Comment: It would not return this value; so please update your question with the actual code you are using.

Comment: Yep, sorry - I was calling `strtotime()` as well. I'll just add an extra day to the date.

Answer (score 3):

date works on a timestamp not a textual representation of a date

If you change the 0 to a 1 for day of month (thus getting a valid date to start from) and use strtotime

`date('F Y', strtotime('2013-05-01T00:00:00'));`

Then it will work

Answer (score 2):

PHP interprets day of the month 0 as the last day of the previous month.

Valid values for day of the month are 01-31

```
echo date('d F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 2013)); //30 April 2013

echo date('d F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2013)); // 01 May 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date('F Y', strtotime('2013-05-00T00:00:00'));
```

`0` is not a valid start date. You have to assign it to `1`. Then it will work as you expected.

```
date('F Y', strtotime('2013-05-01T00:00:00'));
```